# Merge operator only emits the results of the first observable in list

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to use the merge operator to combine four different observables that all emit the same type `T`. I want to merge the four observables so that I have a single observable that emits `T[]` and then I can map the resultant list.

However I've noticed that when the merged observable is being subscribed to, only the results of the first observable in the list are being emitted. Why is this?

I thought it might have something to do with the map that's being used, but if the result of the merged observable is being emitted as a single stream this shouldn't be an issue, surely?

```
this._signalRService.categoryGroupChangeSignal.pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroyObservables),
          switchMap(changedCategoryGroupId => {
                      return this.getAllCategoryGroups$().pipe(
                          map(groups => [changedCategoryGroupId, groups])
                      );
              }
          )).subscribe(([changedCategoryGroupId, groups]: [string, CategoryGroup[]]) => {
          //do stuff with merged groups list 
      });

getAllCategoryGroups$ = (): Observable<CategoryGroup[]> => {

        return this.tenantListService.tenantList.pipe(switchMap( (tenantList: Tenant[]) => {
          return merge(
            this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[0].id),
            this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[1].id),
            this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[2].id)
            )
        }));
  };
```

Comment: Any chance you can show where you're subscribing to it? Or create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` operator does not output an Array with the values of all your observables. It emits a single value if any of your source observables emits a new value.

What you want to achieve can be done with [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest):

```
return this.tenantListService.tenantList.pipe(switchMap( (tenantList: Tenant[]) => {
          return combineLatest(
            this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[0].id),
            this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[1].id),
            this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[2].id)
            )
        }));
```

This will output an array with the latest values of your source observables. But it only emits if all of your source observables emitted at least one value!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single observable that emits T[], I would recommend using [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest). CombineLatest will wait till everything has emitted a value then emit an array of all of the values, and every time a new value is emitted the most recent values for all of them will be emitted. Whereas merge emits them one at a time and only the observable that emits will give you a value.

It is important to note that combineLatest will not emit any values until **EVERY** observable you provided it, in your case the 3 different ones, have emitted at least 1 value.

The syntax for combineLatest is the same so you would simply just have to add combineLatest to your rxjs imports and change merge to combineLatest in your getAllCategoryGroups$.

```
getAllCategoryGroups$ = (): Observable<CategoryGroup[]> => {

    return this.tenantListService.tenantList.pipe(switchMap( (tenantList: Tenant[]) => {
      return combineLatest(
        this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[0].id),
        this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[1].id),
        this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[2].id)
        )
    }));
```

};

Then when you subscribe to it you will receive an array with the same length as the number of observables in your combineLatest

To flatten the array of arrays you can use the [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator which allows you to alter the output the is passed down the observable chain. Once inside of the map there are various ways you can flatten the array I usually just do something like this though:

```
getAllCategoryGroups$ = (): Observable<CategoryGroup[]> => {

    return this.tenantListService.tenantList.pipe(switchMap( (tenantList: Tenant[]) => {
      return combineLatest(
        this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[0].id),
        this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[1].id),
        this._categoryGroupService.getCustomTenantCategoryGroups(tenantList[2].id)
        ).pipe(
             map(lists => {
                const arrayToReturn = [];
                for (const list of lists) {
                    arrayToReturn.push(...list);
                }

                return arrayToReturn;
             })
        )
    }));
```

};

Comment: This is more like what I wanted. Now when I use combine latest I get a list of three lists, with the inner list containing the details I need. Is there an operator I can use to flatten the lists out into a single list of all the details? Also my IDE is saying combineLatest has been deprecated, is there a different version I should be using?

Comment: one of the parameters from comineLatest was deprecated, the function itself was not. It says to pipe to map instead of using that parameter, which is what I did in my update, although we weren't using that parameter to begin with. But make sure your using combineLatest from rxjs NOT the one from rxjs/operators the one form operators is deprecated